# Get the array of objects from query parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, query-string

I'm trying to parse the array from the url query parameters. The url is as below which contains the array of emp objects specified in query parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/list?emp[0].id=21&emp[0].name=john&emp[1].id=22&emp[1].name=tom
```

Can someone please help me with the function that will parse such query params(with some ReGEX maybe) and returns the array as below

```
[{id:'21',name:'john'},{id:'22',name:'tom'}]
```

**Note:** There could be any number of emp objects mentioned in the query params, for example purpose I've just added two.
I've looked for similar solutions but none of them seems to return the array which has its objects specified in the query params with the index value. So please don't mark the question as duplicate

**Edit:** I've written the below function which works for fetching simple query params but doesn't work for array of objects specified in query param as above.

```
export const getQueryParamByName = (name, url) => {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)');
    const results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far, show your code and what doesn't work for you

Comment: try to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Max already tried that, but that doesn't work for array prams as mentioned in my question. Please read carefully

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/bHxanx/2) help?

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my try:

```js
var url = `http://localhost:8080/list?emp[0].id=21&emp[0].name=john&emp[1].id=22&emp[1].name=tom`;
var data = url.split('?')[1].split('&');

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
   key = elem.match(/\d+/)[0];
   kv = elem.split(".")[1].split('=');
   acc[key] = {...(acc[key] || []), ...{[kv[0]]:kv[1]}}
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may match `id` and `name` pair with the following regex:

```
(emp\[\d+]\.)id=(\d+)&\1name=([^&]+)
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/SOqRrY/1))

and then iterate through all such matches returned by [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to build the array of id-name objects:

```js
const extractObjects = url => {
  const regex = /(emp\[\d+]\.)id=(\d+)&\1name=([^&]+)/g;
  const result = [];
  for (const match of url.matchAll(regex)) {
    result.push({id: match[2], name: match[3]});
  }
  return result;
}

const url = 'http://localhost:8080/list?emp[0].id=21&emp[0].name=john&emp[1].id=22&emp[1].name=tom';
const objects = extractObjects(url);
console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a generic function to handle the layed problem:

```
var url = '?person[0].name=Jack&person[0].id=1&person[1].name=Jonathan&note=book';

function removeFirstChar (string) {
  var tmp = string.split('');
  tmp.splice(0 , 1); 
  return tmp.join('');
}

function parse (url) {
  url = removeFirstChar(url);
  var queryParamsArray = url.split('&');

  var object = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < queryParamsArray.length; i++) {
    var queryParamArray = queryParamsArray[i].split('=');
    var re = /\[(\d*)\]/;

    if (re.test(queryParamArray[0])) {
      var reString = /\w+/g;
      var base = (((queryParamArray[0].split('.'))[0]).match(reString))[0];
      var property = (queryParamArray[0].split('.'))[1];

      if (!object[base]) {
        object[base] = [];
      }

      const urlParts = re.exec(queryParamArray[0]);
      const index = urlParts[1];

      if (object[base][index]) {
        object[base][index][property] = queryParamArray[1];
      } else {
        object[base][index] = {
          [property]: queryParamArray[1]
        }
      }
    } else {
      object[queryParamArray[0]] = queryParamArray[1];
    }
  }

  return object;
}
```

It will create an object with all the properties from the query string, the example query string provided will generate the following object:

```
{
    person: [
        {
            name: 'Jack',
            id: '1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jonathan'
        }
    ],
    note: 'book'
}
```